# return reference to unique_ptr in set

Tags: c++, set, unique-ptr

I have a class, Entity, and that class has a property called componentSet. This is a set of unique_ptr's to another class, Component. Each component object has a property called actionStringSet, a set containing strings.

What I want to do is write a member function for Entity that takes a string argument, and returns a reference to whichever component has that string in actionStringSet. They should be unique, so I don't need any special handling if it is in more than one. Also, I'm not sure what to do if none of the components have this string.

What I have so far is:

```
Component& Entity::get_component_for_action(std::string actionStr) {
    std::cout << componentSet.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto& comp : componentSet) {
        std::cout << comp->name;
        if (comp->actionStringSet.count(actionStr)) {
            return comp;
        }
    }
    throw;
}
```

What I would do in python is return None if nothing was found. I can't do this here, so my first though was to instead raise an error, and catch that in all callers. But I'm pretty sure exceptions aren't supposed to be used in c++ like that.

Anyway, the above code will not compile, saying

```
/home/jagoly/Projects/sqee/libsqee/logic/entity.cpp:20: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'sq::Component' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'const std::unique_ptr<sq::Component, std::default_delete<sq::Component> >'
            return comp;
                   ^~~~
```

But that tries to return the pointer itself. I fiddled with changing everything else to expect a unique_ptr, but then I just got errors saying that things had been deleted (I'd assume passing around the pointers are not a good idea).

Anyway, what should I change? Is it just a small bit of syntax in that function, do I need to change my data types, or is my approach fundamentally wrong?

Thanks in advanced :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should dereference the `unique_ptr` to get a reference to the pointed-to value:

```
return *comp;
```

Note that this reference will be invalidated if the `unique_ptr` releases its value, so you should be careful about the lifetime of the elements of the `componentSet` relative to the returned reference.

Comment: I'm still getting used to the differences between references and pointers. And the syntax. Thanks again :D

Comment: @Jagoly: Don't worry too much, the syntax of references and pointers is the hardest part.